# Remove one row when applying a function to columns via a loop

Tags: r

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
    cola = runif(10, min=0, max=100),
    colb = runif(10, min=0, max=100),
    colc = runif(10, min=0, max=100))
df
```

Output of the above script is:

```
         cola     colb      colc
1  11.3703411 69.35913 31.661245
2  62.2299405 54.49748 30.269337
3  60.9274733 28.27336 15.904600
4  62.3379442 92.34335  3.999592
5  86.0915384 29.23158 21.879954
6  64.0310605 83.72956 81.059855
7   0.9495756 28.62233 52.569755
8  23.2550506 26.68208 91.465817
9  66.6083758 18.67228 83.134505
10 51.4251141 23.22259  4.577026
```

My purpose:if `one cell value < mean(column)+10`,I will remove whole `row`.
For example,
In `row 1`,`df[1,'cola']`<`mean(df$cola)`,then `row 1` will be removed.
In `row 2`, because `df[2,'colc']`<`mean(df$colc)`,then `row 2` will be removed.

Finally,the expected result is:

```
      cola     colb      colc
6    64.0310605 83.72956 81.059855
```

I can use `subset(df,cola>mean(cola)+10 & colb>mean(colb)+10 & colc>mean(colc)+10)` to get the expect result,but that's not a smart method when there's hundreds of columns in the data frame.

It seems the `apply` family of functions should be used.How can I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're looking for `filter` from `dplyr` or base `Filter`.

Comment: @NelsonGon, make answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply`(this might be slow):

```
Res<-as.data.frame(apply(df,2,function(x) ifelse(x<mean(x)+10,0,x)))
Res[!apply(Res,1,function(x) any(x==0)),]
```

Result:

```
cola     colb     colc
6 64.03106 83.72956 81.05986
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `colMeans` to get mean for each column, then iterate over each row comparing each value against its mean (using `sapply`), finally, select row where all results are TRUE (using `[`).

```
> Means <- colMeans(df)+10
> ind <- sapply(seq_along(Means), function(i) df[,i] > Means[i] )
> df[rowSums(ind*1) == ncol(df), ]
      cola     colb     colc
6 64.03106 83.72956 81.05986
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner solution using `rowSums` and `colMeans`

```
df[rowSums(df < (colMeans(df) + 10)) == 0, ]
#      cola     colb     colc
#6 64.03106 83.72956 81.05986
```

---

Or `dplyr` version using `filter_all` and `all_vars`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_all(all_vars(. > (mean(.) + 10)))
```